# Where does this hour come from?

Tags: javascript, date

The following creates an array of weeks (of days) for the specified month.

The output looks like this:

```
[
  [
    "2017-06-01T01:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-06-02T01:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-06-03T01:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-06-04T01:00:00.000Z"
  ],
  ...
]
```

Where has that additional hour come from? I was expecting the times to all be midnight?

I am in the UK (BST) currently.

```js
function monthWeeks(month, year) {
  var currentMonth = month - 1;
  var date = utcDate(new Date(year, currentMonth, 1));
  var weeks = [];
  var week;
  while (date.getMonth() === currentMonth) {    
    if(date.getDay() === 1 || !week) {
      week = [];
      weeks.push(week);
    }
    week.push(utcDate(date));   
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return weeks;
}

function utcDate(date) {
  return new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(),
    date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()));
}

console.log(monthWeeks(6, 2017));
```

Comment: For me it's correctly showing `05:30` which is my time zone in India (+5:30)

Comment: Its your current timezone difference with GMT. You are 1 hour ahead of GMT. That's why there is 1 hour added.

Comment: I thought my code was all in UTC. Where is the additional hour creeping in?

Comment: The weeks you're getting aren't ISO weeks, which start on the first Monday of the month. All you need to do is not set the hour, minute and second in *utcDate* so they default to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values that you are seeing are correct.
BST is exactly one hour ahead of UTC.

```js
function monthWeeks(month, year) {
  var currentMonth = month - 1;
  var date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, currentMonth, 1));
  var weeks = [];
  var week;
  while (date.getMonth() === currentMonth) {    
    if(date.getDay() === 1 || !week) {
      week = [];
      weeks.push(week);
    }
    week.push(new Date(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return weeks;
}

console.log(monthWeeks(6, 2017));
```

Comment: But I thought I was adding UTC dates to the arrays. I mean `var date = utcDate(new Date(year, currentMonth, 1));` should surely create a UTC midnight date? I thought my code was "all in UTC" - where is it not?

Comment: The above added snippet is all in UTC

Comment: If you ask me you can just send the year and month to the utcDate(date) function itself

Comment: Your code snippet merely exacerbates the issue and now shows `T02:00:00` for each outputted date-time.

Comment: I just realized it. Working on it.

Comment: @BenAston Fixed it! Try it now!

Comment: OK thanks. So the idea is that a UTC datetime is created `var date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, currentMonth, 1))`, and the `week.push(new Date(date));` does not lose the timezone information. Final question: `getDay`, `getMonth` etc all operate in the local timezone - so why does this code appear to work? Why do I not have to use `getUTCDay` and `getUTCMonth`?

Comment: `week.push(new Date(date))` is not so that it doesn't lose timezone information, It's so that the reference to date is not pushed into the weeks array. Try directly pushing date like `week.push(date)` you will get last value of date as all of your entries.

Comment: `getDay()` and `getMonth()` is timezone based sure, but here it works since the date variable you are checking it on is a UTC date value. `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, 1))`

Comment: But MDN says "The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time". I took that to mean computer-local time. So that would give a value translated from UTC to BST (in my case)?

Comment: It depends on the variable you are running it on. MDN document assumed you did a normal date variable creation

Comment: Well that is my interpretation of that.

Answer (score 1):

The time you are getting is right. The code you are running is in your browser that is based on your local timezone. The timestring you are getting is UTC time.

So as you are in London you are 1 hour ahead of UTC. So if you are creating a datestring where you want it to be midnight. The UTC midnight will be 1 AM in london.

It will depend on which timezone you are running your client code. So in USA, lets say EST timezone is 5 hours behind the UTC. So your code in EST timezone client browser will show `"2017-05-31T19:00:00.000Z"` i.e 5 hours behind.

UTC is standard time, with respect to all other timezones are referenced. So whenever you are getting UTC timestring, don't confuse it with your local timezone. It will always be different. If its midnight in London, it won't be midnight in America ( EST ). So your client date time code will behave differently.

> Just a Tip : If you want to avoid the confusion of timezones and you are 
>   interested in date part only, no matter what timezone. Just truncate the
>   time part and go with Date. It will be less confusing and more
>   uniformly adapted.

Comment: If EST is -0500 then then midnight is be 19:00Z, not 20:00Z.

Comment: Ohh Yes, thanks for correcting. Also US observes daylight saving. That is again a tricky part to handle.